# AjaxFileUpload Control in ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on asp.net webforms project and have installed 19.1 from https://go.devexpress.com/AjaxControlToolkit_Website_Download.aspx in my visual studio 2019 community adition. I tried a simple AjaxFileUpload control but unable to use it. Here are web.config,.aspx.cs & .aspx files.

.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>

    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>

  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>

    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*"
        path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
        type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
          AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

.cs

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") + e.FileName;
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);

    }
```

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AjaxToolKit.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
```

I get red colored error message and unable to upload any file of various types. Further i tired to create a break point but the compiler doesn't stops there. Please help

Comment: Dear All, The problem was with the application pool as well as permissions on uploads folder. I assigned DefaultAppPool and IUSR permission to the application in IIS and it worked great. Thanks